# I'm scraping from Finviz, how do I correct the 1.17B result to standard form? (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping

So I have the input to scrape on Google Sheets as follows:

**=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE( index(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&$C7,"table", 9),3,2),"*",""))**

The **C7** box contains the ticker **SBSW** and the result shows **1.17B**, however because there is the B, it is showing #VALUE!

I'd like to know how to *convert the 1.17B to the Standard form of the number*. How can I adapt my current code to accomplish that?

Edit: the same issue occurs with '-' (hyphen) results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regexextract()` and `regexreplace()`, like this:

```
=value( 
  regexextract( 
    regexreplace( 
      regexreplace( 
        query( 
          importhtml("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" & C7, "table", 9), 
          "select Col2 where Col1 = 'Income' ", 0 
        ), 
        "B", "e9" 
      ), 
      "M", "e6" 
    ), 
    "[-\d.e]+" 
  ) 
)
```

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this helps remove the B. Is there a way I can set it so that B becomes billion and M becomes million? That way I can ensure that the true value is maintained regardless.

Comment: Edited the answer. Use **Format > Number** to present the result in your preferred number format.

Comment: I had to reread this a few times, thank you so much!